# Trying to replace 1 value with a conditional replaces the whole column

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook

Dim lrow As Long
lrow = WB.Sheets("Updated Sheet").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = WB.Sheets("Updated Sheet").Range("R2:R" & lrow)
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long

row = WB.Sheets("Updated Sheet").Range("AJ2").row
col = WB.Sheets("Updated Sheet").Range("AJ2").Column

For Each cl In myrange  'myrange is basically column "R"

If wb.Sheets("Updated Sheet").Cells(row, col) = "Paid" Then
cl.value = "Paid"
Else
End If
row = row + 1
Next cl
```

This is the code I currently have for an if statement where I want to replace the value in column R with the string "Paid" if the value in (row, col) is "Paid" as well.

However, the function currently replaces all values in column R even if there is only one "Paid" match, even though running through with f8/adding a msgbox line shows that the value in cell(row, col) is not "paid" for every line.

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Try changing this: `.Cells(row, "R").` to this: `.Range("R" & row)`

Comment: Where does the `cl` fit into it as it's not used in your loop? Also `col` never changes. @JohnBustos - that's just another way of saying the same thing?

Comment: you're right, I initially used cl to go through row R which was the range of myrange, but I tried an alternate method without taking out the cl part. I have updated the code, and added the rest of it as well. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Autofilter` instead of looping through cells.

Please give this a try...

```
Sub David()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Sheets("Updated Sheet")
WS.AutoFilterMode = False
lrow = WB.Sheets("Updated Sheet").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
With WS.Range("AJ1:AJ" & lrow)
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Paid"
    If WS.Range("R1:R" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        WS.Range("R2:R" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "Paid"
    End If
    .AutoFilter
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, this worked! I've never used autofilter before, could you possibly run through your code for me?

Answer (score 0):

Add .value to your cell reference. Currrently you are comparing a string with a cell object. That could lead to strange results.

```
If wb.Sheets("Updated Sheet").Cells(row, col).value = "Paid" Then
```

Comment: it didn't work in this case, but I'll definitely keep that in mind!

Comment: Hm, strange. Could you add a boolean variable to your code and set it equal to the expression in the IF clause. Then step through the code and check if it even comes back false in any of the lines.